# Show that $2x=\tan x$ has infinitely many solutions using the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

I understand what the Intermediate Value Theorem is, but am not sure how to apply it to a $\tan x$ function being that there are many points of discontinuity.

Comment: Show that there is a solution in the interval $\left[2n\pi, 2n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ for every positive integer $n$. In this interval the tangent function is continuous.

Comment: **HINT** Let $f(x)=2x-\tan(x)$, find an interval $[a,b]$ where $f$ is a continuous function and $0 \in [f(a), f(b)]$ (why you can always do this?). Then use that you can find different infinitely many such intervals (by jumping on the branches of $\tan$).

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(x)$ is continuous on $[n\pi, n\pi + \pi/2)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, it attains every value in $[0,\infty)$ in that interval for each $n$. In particular, it attains the value $2x$ once in each interval. Thus, the equation $2x = \tan(x)$ has infinitely many solutions.